# How to set height of UITableView to solve scrolling issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

**Background**: I'm working on my first iOS app that uses a UITableView for data being loaded dynamically from a web source.  No, this is not homework.

**Problem**: When I scroll down the list bounces back to the top.

**Things I've Tried**:

1. This [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1507986/2521004) (reducing the size of the table view) works but now I have large space at the bottom of the screen.
2. I've tried using `[tableView reloadData]` but this doesn't changing the behavior.  I even hooked this up to a button to make sure it was firing after the view was populated.
3. I also read a few post about `contentSize` and how to calculate based on the amount of data loaded in the table.  This looks like the solution I need but am having trouble getting a clear explanation of how to implement it for my setup.

**Code**:

I started a new project with single view application template and added a `UITableView` to the default view in the main storyboard.

In view controller I have the following (relevant) code:

```
@interface ERViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myArray;
@property (nonatomic,retain) UITableView *tableView;
@end

@implementation ERViewController
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
}
```

---

Here I am loading the data from Parse.com into my table and then calling `[self loadView]` to get the view to update after the query finishes.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSMutableArray *returnedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Persons"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                //NSLog(@"display name: %@",object[@"firstName"]);
                [returnedData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", object[@"lastName"],object[@"firstName"]]];
            }

            tableData = returnedData;

            // Reload view to display data
            [self loadView];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    // Configure the cell
    cell.textLabel.text = [tableData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSArray *itemArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"✔︎", @"?", @"X", nil];

    UISegmentedControl *mainSegment = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];

    mainSegment.frame = CGRectMake(200,0, 100, 43);
    self.navigationItem.titleView = mainSegment;
    mainSegment.selectedSegmentIndex = [itemArray count];

    [mainSegment addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(mainSegmentControl:)
          forControlEvents: UIControlEventValueChanged];
    mainSegment.tag = indexPath.row;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:mainSegment];

    return cell;
}
```

---

Sample screen shot:

[image]

---

Since I'm waiting for the data to load I'm not sure where to resize the view and how exactly I need to resize the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *never ever* manually call `loadView`.

Once you have your `tableData` call [`reloadData`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/reloadData) on the `tableView`.

You should also load you table data in `viewDidAppear:`, and if you only want to do it once, create a flag to see if its already been loaded. While waiting for the data to load, `tableData` will be `nil` so if you query the `count` of it, you will be messaging a `nil` object and therefore it would act like returning `0`.

Finally you should not be touching the `contentSize` of the table view, it handles that itself. You just need to make sure that in Interface Builder, the table view's frame is the same as the root views frame.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    NSMutableArray *returnedData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Persons"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            for (PFObject *object in objects) {
                //NSLog(@"display name: %@",object[@"firstName"]);
                [returnedData addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@", object[@"lastName"],object[@"firstName"]]];
            }

            tableData = returnedData;

            // Reload view to display data
            [self.tableView reloadData];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        }
    }];
}
```

If you just want a `UIViewController` with only a `UITableView` in it, consider using a [`UITableViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: Thank you for all the helpful suggestions, obviously I'm pretty new to Objective C.  When I try `reloadData` I get an error stating: `"No visible @interface for 'myViewControler' declares the selector 'reloadData'`.  Is this because of how I'm connecting to the table view?  You can see in my interface posted above that I declare a property for the `tableView` but maybe this is also a bad practice.

Comment: Oh sorry that's a typo on my part, it should be `[self.tableView reloadData]`. I've fixed in in my answer.

Comment: Okay, I've moved the code over to `viewDidAppear` and am using `reloadData`.  Now I went to the interface builder and stretched bottom handle of the table view down to the bottom of the view controller (snapped to blue helper line).  The view still doesn't allow me to scroll down to the bottom, it bounces back to the top. Any other ideas?

Comment: Are you using autolayout in your Storyboard?

Comment: Yes, `Use Auto Layout` is checked. I just switched the simulator over to `iPhone Retina (4 inch)` and it ran with no problems, Switched back to 3.5 inch and the problem returned.  I also ran it directly on a iPhone 4s developer phone and I could scroll but not all the way to the bottom.

Comment: Have you setup the constraints correctly so the table view is pinned to all the root view edges. Like I mentioned in my answer, if you only have a table view in your view controller, why not just use a table view controller?

Comment: I created a new `UITableViewController` as you  suggested and it works.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Posted for others dealing with the same problem I had and can't just move to a different view controller.

To solve the problem with a `UITableView` within a general view controller (not `UITableViewController`) click the little icon below the view controller that looks like this:

[image]

The button is titled "Resolve Auto Layout Issues"

Select "Reset to suggested constraints in View Controller"

This fixed all my scrolling issues since I must have been incorrectly snapping to the auto layout edges.